# Where to insert sitemap.xml file in NextJS project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sitemap

I just finished my NextJS webpage and simply used online sitemap generator to get my sitemap.xml file. I was used to putting it in my public folder when using ReactJS or dist folder in case of regular HTML, CSS and Vanilla JS structure. Where can I add it in my NextJS project so it is accessible like this: [www.example.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml) ?

Here is a screenshot of my file structure:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out in future, I found a solution. Simply create a folder called "public" in your NextJS project and add sitemap.xml file there. Now I can access it from [www.example.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there, Did you find a way to create a dynamic sitemap file?